# Error SQL: ORA-02376: recurso no válido o redundante

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have this problem with the follow sentence in Oracle 12c.

```
Error que empieza en la línea 1 del comando:
CREATE PROFILE "ORA_STIG_PROFILE" LIMIT COMPOSITE_LIMIT DEFAULT SESSIONS_PER_USER DEFAULT CPU_PER_SESSION DEFAULT CPU_PER_CALL DEFAULT LOGICAL_READS_PER_SESSION DEFAULT LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL DEFAULT IDLE_TIME 15 CONNECT_TIME DEFAULT PRIVATE_SGA DEFAULT FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 3 PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME 5184000/86400 PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME 31536000/86400 PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX 10 PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME UNLIMITED PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME 432000/86400 INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_TIME 3024000
Error en la línea de comandos:1 Columna:431
Informe de error:
Error SQL: ORA-02376: recurso no válido o redundante
02376. 00000 -  "invalid or redundant resource"
*Cause:    a create, or alter profile command which names a resource not
           defined, or try to specify same resource twice.
*Action:   define resource first
```

My server version is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Any Help! Thanks!!!

This sentence is in a .dump file, but I tried to exec in a SQL Developer.

Comment: The error refers to line 1 character 431. Character 431 is the 'I' at the start of `INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_TIME`. The `INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_TIME` clause [was added in 12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/release-changes.html#GUID-BE8B5BDA-8AE1-4958-9896-0B082954CE73) - so it isn't valid in 12.1. Presumably your dump is from an export done in a later version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use 12c, here's [CREATE PROFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6012.htm#SQLRF01310) documentation valid for that database version.

If you check it, you'll see that there's no `INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_TIME` so - remove it. That's what error says, "**invalid** resource".